# How to add text to sender ID in kannel

Tags: kannel

I am sending sms using (http:/ myIP:13013/cgi-bin/sendsms?from=XXXX&username=kannel&password=kannel&text=TESTSMS&to=9122222288) in Kannel

I am able to send sms successfully. I receive SMS 
as

Sender : - XXXX

sms Body :- TESTSMS

In this case my sender id is XXXX.

Now I want to add my own text to Sender ID eg. XXXX - Welcome TO Kannel

So what changes I need to do in kannel configuration.

Expected SMS:

Sender : - XXXX - Welcome TO Kannel

SMS Body : - TESTSMS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sender ID is what you've specified in the `from` parameter in the sendsms URL, i.e., this here: [...]from=**XXXX**&username=[...]

You don't need to change Kannel configuration to change the sender text, just change the value in the URL. You do have to take into account that:

1. The value should be [URL-encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).
2. It must be between 3-11 alphanumeric characters (letters, numbers and underscore according to the GSM standard.) In practice some other characters also work 99% of the time. In practice also sometimes shorter sender IDs work but it depends on your SMS gateway, recipient operator, and recipient phone.
3. Or it can be up to 15 digits if it's numeric, then Kannel will treat it as a phone number in international format (i.e., as if it's a phone number with country code added in front.)

Comment: Sir, Thanx for your reply. But I want to ask that I will use from=XXXX only in the URL and is there any parameter that will add my own string  "Welcome TO Kannel" at runtime while sending message to XXXX.

Comment: @user2833700 `to` is the parameter for the recipient number; `from` *is* the sender ID.

Answer (score 0):

You have to alter the sender id outside kannel and then use your common HTTP request with altered sender id. Your sender id mustn't contain whitespaces, you can use "%20" instead.